# Better way to get count in single column based on two conditions in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query for following problem statement.
I want to write a query where I can find Valid and Invalid visa.
There are currently two visa types in my table

1. Business Visa
2. Work Permit

I have main table *tbl_employee_visa_request* where I have stored all the requests raised by employee.

I have two tables (*tbl_visa_request_status* and *tbl_uscis*) where I have to check if any visa is valid.

Structure for *tbl_visa_request_status* is

```
id | requestId| visaStartDate|visaEndDate
-----------------------------------------
 1 | 123| 01-01-2017|31-03-2017
 2 | 567| 01-01-2017|19-12-2018
 3 | 45456| 01-01-2017|01-01-2016
 4 | 56756| 01-01-2017|17-03-2017
 5 | 343| 01-01-2017|01-01-2019
```

*tbl_uscis*

```
 id | requestId| caseNumber|isActive
    -----------------------------------------
     1 | 123| A435|1
     2 | 567| 1BCFG324|0
     3 | 45456| 234R|0
     4 | 56756| AB456|1
     5 | 343| AKO45|1
```

If I have to check validity of **Work Permit** Visa then I have to check *isActive* field in *tbl_uscis*. If 0 then Invalid and if 1 then Valid.

If I want to check validity of **Business Visa** then I have to compare 
*visaEndDate* in *tbl_visa_request_status* with current date. If EndDate is greater than current date then Valid else Invalid.

I have written a query to achieve this functionality by using **union** of two queries as follows :

```
SELECT vt.`visa_type` AS visaType
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vrs.`visa_end_date` > NOW() THEN 1 END) AS Valid
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vrs.`visa_end_date` < NOW() THEN 1 END) AS InValid
        FROM `tbl_visa_request_status` vrs
        LEFT JOIN `tbl_employee_visa_request` evr 
        ON evr.id = vrs.`tbl_employee_visa_request_id`
        LEFT JOIN `tbl_visa_type` vt
        ON evr.`tbl_visa_type_id` = vt.`id`
        WHERE evr.`tbl_visa_type_id` != 2
        GROUP BY evr.`tbl_visa_type_id`

        UNION

        SELECT vt.`visa_type` AS visaType
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN u.`is_active` = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Valid
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN u.`is_active` = 0 THEN 1 END) AS InValid
        FROM `tbl_uscis` u
        LEFT JOIN `tbl_employee_visa_request` evr 
        ON evr.id = u.`tbl_employee_visa_request_id`
        LEFT JOIN `tbl_visa_type` vt
        ON evr.`tbl_visa_type_id` = vt.`id`
        GROUP BY evr.`tbl_visa_type_id`;
```

[image]

I get output as in image.

But my problem is when there is new visa type where I have to check different conditions for validity then I will have to write a new query which will be union with current query.

What I am trying to find out is that is there a better way to achieve this functionality where instead of writing a whole new query I can simply change only some conditions in **where clause** of a single query when a new visa type gets added in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the validity criteria in a single table for all types of visas in order not to have to rewrite the query if you add a new visa type.

As long as the details of the different types are stored in different queries, you will have to change your query every time you add a new visa type. You may use joins instead of unions, but still a new visa type would mean a new join.

I would create a single `visas` table that would hold all the common data for all visas, which would include validity start and end dates (I have never seen a visa without these 2 dates). You can use these data to write a single query that does not even have to be modified if you add a new visa type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try doing this approach